# Resharper complaining about angular2 object in typescript

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, angular, typescript1.7

I am using Resharper 10 in Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

As indicated by the green box in the screenshot, it complains a valid decorator syntax with the error:

> Cannot convert type 'any' to type '(target: TFunction) => TFunction | void'.

Also, as shown in the blue box, it couldn't recognize the **Router** class that was exported from Angular library.

This code compiles in typescript with no problem.

Is this a known bug in Resharper?

Note: I am using Visual Studio ***2015 with update 1***, Resharper ***10.0.2***, Typescript ***1.7.4*** and Angular2 ***2.0.0-beta.0***

Answer (score 1):

ReSharper 10.0 had problems with resolving types from NPM packages.

It's fixed in ReSharper 10.1. Please try 10.1 EAP:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+10.1+EAP

Comment: Hi @Anton, Thanks for answering. I cannot confirm this as I am unable to download EAP on my corporate environment. I guess, I will have to wait till they release this version.